# Have you a name?

Tags: questions, subject-verb-inversion

In [The Dig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dig_(video_game)), a video game, character Maggie asks a question this way (full script [here](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/pc/9487-the-dig/faqs/61059?page=3)):

> MAGGIE: Have you a name?
>
> CREATOR: I had a name, when I was alive. Now that I am again and again dead, what need have I for names? (...)

This is not regular [inversion](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/inversion), since "have" here is not an auxiliary verb.

What's happening in that sentence?

Comment: It is subject-auxiliary inversion. "Have" is an auxiliary in your examples. If it was a lexical verb it would require _do_ support as in "Do you have a name?" / "... what need do I have for names?"

Comment: Have you a name is more British than American English. It is just an alternative to: Do you have a name.

Comment: 'Have need for' is a fixed [transitive, verbo-nominal] phrase, often used interrogatively after 'what' ('What need has he for ...?) It is an idiom, as 'have desire/yearning for' is not available (though 'have **a** desire/yearning', and also 'have **a** need' 'for' are of course acceptable). Idioms are by definition strangely behaved.

Comment: It seems an attempt to write archaic dialog for someone who's presumably been dead a while. It's not standard modern English; whether all of it was ever standard English, is an open question.

Comment: It's not normal American English. _Have_ in the sense of 'possess' isn't treated as an auxiliary in American English. But we do understand when somebody else does it, although it sounds fake if it's not a UK accent.

Comment: @StuartF Early Modern English - *M't:26:65: Then the high priest rent his clothes, saying, He hath spoken blasphemy; **what further need have we of witnesses?** behold, now ye have heard his blasphemy.* - It was usually "need of" rather than "need for".

Answer (score 1):

This usage of "have" is generally acceptable in British English but not in American English. It undergoes subject/auxiliary inversion even without a verb after it, just as "to be" is inverted both in "Are you hungry?" and in "Are you working?".

Comment: Any source or examples?